# calculating sum in objects

Tags: php, object

I am in need to do this thing:
I have an object like below, but i am in need to do the sum of the numbers of objects like  object1_(anything), object2_(anything)

```
stdClass Object
(
    [object1_2012_06_12] => 16
    [object2_2012_06_12] => 10
    [object1_2012_06_11] => 16
    [object2_2012_06_11] => 10
)
```

For examaple: sum of **object1_(*anything*)** will be (object1_2012_06_12 + object1_2012_06_11) = (16+16)=32

Comment: Sorry for been unconstructive here but I would strongly recommend you change that design to an array of objects. It doesn't sit well with OOP

Comment: means, there is no way to do this?

Comment: No it doesn't Mohan, it means your design makes it more complicated than it need be, not impossible

Comment: You design will work but

Comment: Your design will work but maintaining it will be difficult

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast your object to array:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ((array)$myobj as $v) {
  $sum += intval($v);
}
```

Or as suggested by @MarkBaker:

```
$sum = array_sum((array)$myobj);
```

Comment: I don't want to cast, i just want sum.

Comment: isn't $sum = array_sum((array) $myobj); even easier?

Comment: @MarkBaker man, I've been coding PHP for years and I missed that function. Thanks!

Comment: I have converted the object to array, but don't know how can I do the sum of [array_val_1_2012_06_12] => 16 and [array_val_1_2012_06_11] => 16. dates are dynamically generated. Is there any wildcard as we use in sql like %

Comment: Yea, it's called regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the object attributes and sum based on part before first underscore using `strtok`:

```
$sums = array();
foreach ($my_object as $key => $value) {
    $key = strtok($key, '_');

    if (!isset($sums[$key])) {
            $sums[$key] = $value;
    } else {
            $sums[$key] += $value;
    }
}

print_r($sums);
```

Or:

```
function sum_of_object_starting_with($my_object, $starts_with)
{
    $sum = 0; $prefix_len = strlen($starts_with);
    foreach ($my_object as $key => $value) {
        if (strncmp($key, $starts_with, $prefix_len)) {
            $sum += $value;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

print_r(sum_of_object_starting_with($my_object, 'object1_'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the value you want:

```
function sum_by_object_name ($data, $objName) {

  // Temporary array to hold values for a object name
  $objValues = array();

  // Convert input object to array and iterate over it
  foreach ((array) $data as $key => $val) {

    // Extract the object name portion of the key
    $keyName = implode('_', array_slice(explode('_', $key), 0, -3));

    // If object name is correct push this value onto the temp array
    if ($keyName == $objName) {
      $objValues[] = $val;
    }

  }

  // Return the sum of the temp array
  return array_sum($objValues);

}

// Calculate the total of $object
$total = sum_by_object_name($object, 'object1');
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/n5ph1bCN)